# Why am I getting an incompatible types from the java compiler?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I'm a Java newbie, but I am an experienced programmer (Assembler, COBOL, C/C++, REXX)

I can't understand why the compiler is giving me the following:

```
[loading java\lang\Throwable.class(java\lang:Throwable.class)]
src\LU62XnsCvr.java:265: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: java.lang.StringBuffer
```

Code:

```
message_data = "LU62XCE0513: Request File I/O Exception =" ;
```

I've defined `message_data` as:

```
static StringBuffer message_data = new StringBuffer();
```

So why can't I place a simple literal `String` into the `StringBuffer` labeled `message_data` ? 
I mean BOTH are of type `String` .. right ??

Comment: If possible please share the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both objects may represent a string but they are thechnically not *both of type string*. You can create a stringbuffer from a string directly via `new StringBuffer(message_data)`.

Answer (score 7):

No, `String` and `StringBuffer` are totally unrelated. Try

```
message_data.append("LU62XCE0513: Request File I/O Exception =");
```

While we're at it: note that `StringBuffer` is a legacy class, best replaced with `StringBuilder` in new code, except in the unlikely case that you need to share the object across threads. It's source compatible, so just change the name and you're fine.

Comment: They aren't totally unrelated. Both implement `CharSequence`.

Comment: @glowcoder - `String` "is not a" `StringBuilder` if you want to get picky ;)

Comment: @glowcoder: agree, "totally unrelated" is kinda strong, but it's a common newbie misconception that they're related by inheritance and/or interchangeable in some way. The addition of `CharSequence` actually did make them related by inheritance in a way, but methods that want `CharSequence` arguments are few and far between. Old habits die hard!

Comment: I agree, it is a difficult decision (simplification vs potential confusion) that I myself have come across. I just figured I'd throw it out there. It garners a +1 either way, especially for the notes about `StringBuffer` vs `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score -2):

Just call `message_data.toString()` when passing the message to the `Throwable`